# Persist data downloaded by Celery workers

Tags: python, persistence, message-queue, python-3.x

I'm working in a tool that downloads tweets from Twitter to process them later. For this purpose I'm using Celery with RabbitMQ, sending task with the keywords that must be tracked by the workers.

My problem now is that I must pre-process the tweets downloaded by a worker in a second task so I should merge both tasks to have access to them or persist all tweets in a common storage and fetch them in the new task. Regarding the chosen option I need to persist all tweets for the final processing.

So here is the question. What is the best way to merge and persist all the tweets downloaded by the workers to have access to the whole dataset?

Answer (score 1):

We are using something very similar to this. Can't you add a task that saves the data once it has completed processing them? We use Kombu to download (Consumer) and to Publish (Producer) back to RMQ and celery only has a very specific task which sort of is your case.

- RMQ queue A gets consumed by Consumer
- Message obtained by Consumer gets sent to Celery for processing
- Message returned by Celery is passed to Publisher with results obtained and posted to RMQ queue B.

Hope it helps.